# How to pass data between routes in express.js

Tags: node.js, express

hope someone can help me. Can't find a solution. Maybe I'm also just on the wrong way?
It's a simple express setup and I'm quite new.
I get a response from a request and want to pass a variable/the data from the response to the next route into the URL.
So one parameter in the next URL should be dynamical depending on the response of the first call.

here my whole code:

My problem is where you can see the const sendoutID

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));




// Create Sendout
app.post("/createSendout", (req, res, next) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url: "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId); // View Results

// I want this data "results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId" passing to the next route

       
      }
    }
  );
});


/* here the variable is just hard coded for now but 
I want to pass it in the URL from my previous route 
to the next route see below at + sendoutID +..*/

const sendoutId = 389125;


// Add Respondent
app.post("/addRespondent", (req, res, next) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url:
        "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts/" +
        sendoutId +
        "/respondents",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response);
      //console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results); // View Results
      }
    }
  );
});


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To pass to the next route you can assign `results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId` to  `req.body`

   `req.body.SendoutId = results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId;`

Then you can use that SendoutId in next route.

2. You can pass that variable inside `next()`

   next(results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId);

In the next route you can access it by calling:

```
function nextRoute(SenderId, req, res, next)
```

Edited:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const request = require("request");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const port = 3001;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));




// Create Sendout
app.post("/createSendout", (req, res, next) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url: "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxxxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId); // View Results

// I want this data "results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId" passing to the next route

      req.SendoutId = results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId;
       
      }
    }
  );
}, addRespondent);


/* here the variable is just hard coded for now but 
I want to pass it in the URL from my previous route 
to the next route see below at + sendoutID +..*/

const sendoutId = 389125;


// Add Respondent
app.post("/addRespondent", addRespondent);

function addRespondent(req, res, next) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url:
        "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts/" +
        req.sendoutId +
        "/respondents",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxxxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response);
      //console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results); // View Results
      }
    }
  );
}


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer!
I tried your suggestions but it seems I still do something wrong. 
can you maybe add it in my code so I can double check if I'm adding everythign on the right place?

Comment: you have mentioned that 
I want this data "results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId" passing to the next route.
what do you mean by this?
you want the response to be sent to Create Sendout route?

Comment: I get from the endpoint in the first router a response. in this response is a "sendoutId".
this "sendoutId" needs to be a parameter of the endpoint in the next router. 
url:`https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts/${sendoutId}/respondents`

Comment: Have updated my answer hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately it still doesn't work. I've tried a lot and changex a lot. Checked if every variable is correctly written.. But it still does not recognize the id. It shows in my console and it's the correct one, that I know for sure, but it 's not adding the id as parameter in the URL

Answer (score 0):

1. You should be using a middleware function.

*What is a middleware function?*

-> it's just a function that runs in the middle that is (before a request hits the route and ends before a request completes.[Express Documentation for writing middlewares.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/writing-middleware.html)

***Middleware functions are functions that have access to the request object (req), the response object (res), and the next function.NOTE middleware function does not end the request-response cycle, it must call next() to pass control to the next middleware function. Otherwise, the request will be left hanging.***.

**Advantage** of using a middleware function -> "you can use this function for any other request too in the future", use it in other modules".

2)

```
const captureSendOutIDMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
         req.SendOutID=results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId; //changed "const req" to just req.
             next();

    } catch (error) {
        res.status(401).send({
            error: 'NO SEND OUT ID'
        })
    }
app.post("/CreateSendOut",captureSendOutIDMIddleware,async(req, res) =>{
//do your operation

});

app.post("/addRespondent",async(req,res)=>{

const capturedSendoutID=req.SendoutID;
console.log(capturedSendoutID);
//do you operations

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution, but it didn't work so far. But thanks for the hint with the middleware. I need to have a deeper look in this.

Comment: I have added a correction in the try statement, (changed const req to req=..). Why I removed because const req will create a new variable instead we want to work with the same request, so req.SendoutID will just add a property to the previously existing req object.It should work now.

Comment: thanks!
I've already tried that but didn't work. But I found another solution which works in my first tests. maybe your solution will work now too because I found another "issue" which might be also a cause. I'll post it as a new comment. Thanks anyway for your help :)

Comment: it will work now because earlier by mistake "const req" statement was making a new variable, however when we change it to just to req.SendOutID=results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId; it adds a new property to existing req object.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.
I found now another solution which works as well as I found another issue. Don't know if it was also a cause for why it didn't work, or why your solutions didn't work. But I used app.set() and app.get to pass the data.
The other issue was, that now, with app.set() and app.get() it sometimes worked, sometimes not. So I set a timeout on the call in the frontend, which executes the api requests. Just to have a bit time between.
here is my new code

```
// Create Sendout
app.post("/createSendout", (req, res, next) => {
  request.post(
    {
      url: "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxxxx-xxx-xx-xxxx-xxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId); // View Results
        app.set("surveyId", results.CreateSendoutResult.SendoutId);    // new added line
      }
    }
  );
});


// Add Respondent
app.post("/addRespondent", (req, res, next) => {
  const surveyId = app.get("surveyId");        // new added line
  request.post(
    {
      url:
        "https://www.something.com/api/v1.2/surveys/904211/sendouts/" +
        surveyId +
        "/respondents",
      body: JSON.stringify(req.body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "X-API-KEY": "xxxxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
      },
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
      console.log(response);
      //console.log(response.statusCode);
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        // Successful call
        var results = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(results); // View Results
      }
    }
  );
});
```